# How to auto size a form around a tab control + more controls

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, autosize

I have a form that has several controls:

- `ProgressBar` at the top of the form (docked)
- A `TabControl` at the top of the form (also docked but underneath the progress bar)
- `Buttons`, `TextBoxes` and `labels` inside `TabPages` of the `TabControl`
- `FlowLayoutPanel` at the bottom of the screen (docked) with a few buttons in it
- `Label` at the bottom of the form to act as separator (also docked, but above the  `FlowLayoutPanel`)

I am trying to auto size the form to fit its content. What needs to happen is:

1. Tab pages wrap around its content
2. Tab control wraps around the largest tab page
3. The form wraps around the tab control, progress bar and buttons.

Here's an example of how the form looks **without** `AutoSizeMode` set to `GrowAndShrink` (just `Grow`):

[alt text http://www.fusyion.net/images/Form%20no%20shrink.png](http://www.fusyion.net/images/Form%20no%20shrink.png)

And this is how it looks **with** `AutoSizeMode` set to `GrowAndShrink`:

[alt text http://www.fusyion.net/images/Form%20with%20shrink.png](http://www.fusyion.net/images/Form%20with%20shrink.png)

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this to work, you have to set the `MinimumSize` of all your controls to a value. This will be respected from the Shrink-Mode, thus leading to a well sized form.

Comment: Unfortunately the content of the tab pages varies, so I can't really set a `MinimumSize` for that.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but if you set the MinimumSize of all elements within the TabPage, the TabPage itself should respect this.

Comment: I understand. I think I'll just go for setting the form to a `MinimumSize`, because there are a lot of controls that are dynamically generated. I can't really set a size for all of them. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the direct children of your form have anchors set exactly to `Left` and `Top`. You could set the [Form.MinimumSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize.aspx) and [Form.MaximumSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize.aspx) as a precaution.